2 teenage boys play a Halo-like video game that eventually becomes real
Plot:
2 friends play a new video game. So bad that they are pretty much addicted to it. One of the boy's mother takes the game system from one of them and he flips out. He ends up getting it back and when he turns it on, the game comes to life. It is a Halo type game. He has to put his hand on his TV screen to log into the game. Both boys become part of the game and are on opposing sides. One is the good guy the other is the bad guy.
Extra details:

It is in English. 
An American movie.
Fairly recent.
It may have the word TIME in the title. 
It is not the movie Gamer.


Your description is very vague. Try adding anymore helpful details such as when you saw this movie? if it was an English movie or not? Any description about the characters you could provide would be helpful as well.
Meanwhile, check and let me know if by any chance it was the movie Gamer (2009)? Here's a link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1034032/

@user43595/Sonya: You seems to have two accounts, it's betetr if you merge it . That will help you to appreciate the future answers.  Follow process from here

I don't have 2 accounts. They both show that same number. I logged into the website and then saw there was an app. I downloaded the app and logged in with the same email and password.

You said you may know the answer. Do you?

Sounds like Time Warrior from 2012.

When a pirate version of the most popular first person shooter (FPS) video game, i.e. Call of Duty - lands in the hands of Matt and Jimmy, they immediately think it's the coolest video game they have ever played. Little do they know that while it seams to be their favorite video game, it is actually an evil recruiting device to turn selected kids into real Time Warriors, at the service of 'The Lord of War' - an evil character behind every war since the beginning of time.

It's activated when you put your hands on the screen. They eventually fight one another. The trailer:



